# Proof Verification: $2|n^2-n,\ \forall n\ \in \mathbb Z$

Tags: solution-verification

$$\text{Prove: } 2|n^2-n,\ \forall \ n \in \mathbb Z$$

My Proof is as follows. I am unsure as to how good it is and I presume there is a much better way of proving this that is simpler and clearer.

**Proof:** $2|n^2-n,\ \forall \ n \in \mathbb Z$ there are two cases, 1, when $n$ is odd, and 2, when $n$ is even.

***Case 1:*** Let $n=2k+1$ $$2|(2k+1)^2 - (2k+1) = 4k^2 + 4k +1 - 2k - 1$$ $$2|4k^2 +  2k \ \text{    ...Which is true}$$

***Case 2:*** Let $n=2k$ $$2|(2k)^2 - (2k)  $$ $$2|4k^2 - 2k \ \text{    ...Which is also true}$$

Therefore as both Case 1 & 2 are true $2|n^2-n,\ \forall \ n \in \mathbb Z$

Comment: It is correct! You can also do this with $2 | n^2+n$, and see that $\frac{n^2+n}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=1+2+3+\dots+n$. So $2 | n(n+1)$ and you can replace $n-1$ in $n$ and get the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proof is fine.

Here is how I prove it:

- $n^2-n=n(n-1)$, it's a product of two consecutive integers, hence it is divisible by $2$.

Comment: To add some detail, either $n$ or $n-1$ will be even…the claim follows

Comment: Thank you, that’s a lot simpler than my proof, I will definitely keep this in mind for future proofs.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively notice that $n$ and $n^2$ have the same parity, so their difference is even.

You can prove it in a similar way:

- $n=2k$ then $n^2=4k^2=2(2k^2)=2k'$
- $n=2k+1$ then $n^2=4k^2+4k+1=2(2k^2+2k)+1=2k'+1$

This in facts opens the road to modular arithmetic (that you'll learn later in your studies), i.e.

$n^2\equiv n\pmod 2$ therefore $n^2-n\equiv n-n\equiv 0\pmod 2$